# How to get current UTC time in seconds in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I would want to get current UTC time formatted to `HH:MM:SS`. What is the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.utcnow().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

(answer updated and improved thanks for comments)

Comment: ...or just `datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")`? This seems needlessly hacky.

Comment: this doesn't return UTC neither